Ubuntu 24.04 to not correctly displaying UTF-8 octal on terminal
We have a PAM module that generates a QR display in a terminal that works fine on Ubuntu 20.04. but not Ubuntu 24.04.  Instead of displaying the converted UTF-8 octal codes in the terminal as solids or white space from a Ubuntu 24.04 machine, the  UTF-8 Octal code is displayed.  Also, Unicode \u00AE is displayed as \302\256 instead of the registration mark.
The module is written in C code. What changes are needed for Ubuntu 24.04?
The code line  where the error occurs is
int pam_err2 = pam_prompt(handle, PAM_TEXT_INFO, &response, "%s",qr);

where qr = generate_qr(login_attempt_uuid);
Where the login_attempt_uuid is  returned  as a multiline string of UTF-8 octal codes
The PAM module is in the sshd file with the top line as auth sufficient pam_traitware.U20.s with arguments. It is called through the terminal command SSH name@machineIP Localle has this line LANG=C.UTF-8 The same line as in the 20.04 machine –
HWS
Per recommendation, the environment was added as the
first line of the sshd stack pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale #AUTH LINE FOR TRAITWARE pam auth sufficient pam_traitware.U24.so client_id= –
There was no change in performance, but it still got –  octal codes were displayed in the terminal instead of white space and solids for the QR code.
Example of the display
\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\2 truncated –
Client is a Windows  11 version 23H2
Windows Terminal
Version: 1.20.11781.0
image 20.04 sftp login on 20.04 machine
20.04 login  screen
image of login screen 34.04  machine
24.04 login screen

You could look at the echo code for the -e option, that properly takes the string and converts to the registration mark.

What are your locale and LANG= settings?

In what circumstances is the module invoked (since there are different pam stacks for login vs. ssh vs su etc.)? Where in the stack do you invoke the module - in particular is it before or after any pam_env modules? Do you call pam_env explicitly to set the locale (ex. pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale) and if so does the indicated file define a UTF-8 locale? Please [edit] your question to add these missing details.

The PAM module is in the sshd file with line top line  as auth sufficient pam_traitware.U20.s  with arguments. It is called through the terminal command ssh name@machineIP   Localle has this line LANG=C.UTF-8 The same line as in the 20.04 machine

Added pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale to the sshd  stack

#add to set  the environment
pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
#AUTH LINE FOR TRAITWARE pam
auth sufficient pam_traitware.U24.so client_id=

no change in performance  still  get

\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\226\204\342\2 truncated

still getting the UTF codes   instead of white  space an solids

Please [edit] ALL this new information into your question, along with details of the client system from which you are connecting via SSH.

update was done
